# Cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type IndexPath (Core Data)?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have the following code where I get fetchedObjects from a Core Data stack. How can I access the elements of these? It throws an error saying I need an IndexPath?

```
func loadDataToMapView() {
    guard let mapCoordinates = fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity.fetchedObjects else { return 0 }

    let coordinate2 = fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity.object(at: 1)

    print(coordinate2)
```

Answer (score 13):

`NSFetchedResultsController.object` method required an `IndexPath`. An `IndexPath` is composed by section and row. If you have only one section you can try with this

```
let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
let coordinate2 = fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity.object(at: myIndexPath)
```